# Tile roof has water running under tiles

Tags: roof

recent rains revealed a problem on our portico roof--instead of running into the gutters, the water drips down  the column and in front of the gutters!  So, I went up there and discovered puzzling construction of the flashing channel--tiles broken in half and turned upside down were set there, collecting snail shells and blocking or diverting the water.   Why?  These tiles are those huge hump ones--about 6" dia.   Further up there is a perpendicular wall with 3 humps abutting the flashing,  but no end pieces -- just wide open--a brasserie serving escargot ;  is that normal ?
[dripping from roof](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rG9d8vHjzYw)  How should the abbuttment to flashing be finished off?  I cleared the down channel of the broken tiles and bent the channel lip open so that a pail-of-water test does not drip .  Now I need to find out how to finish the construction of the ends of those 3 runs while still wondering if I need to put those broken tiles back onto the channel.

Thanks

Ed

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture or two of the tile problem would really help us understand how to help you.

Comment: No joy @DanielDriscom;  rains yesterday  dripped through as the video above shows, so the bric brac in the flashing channel is not the problem;  where to look?   How is a flashing channel hooked to a gutter?

Answer (score 1):

Found a handyman with roof tile experience; he put new tar paper under the tiles (3' wide);  but it still leaked during a water hose test!  He then added some drip edging at the gutters (again, 3' wide) and opened an end flap under the tile adjoining the wall;  the dripping stopped with all water caught into the gutter.  And we had a deluge within the week and it worked; cost $700.

And he put those broken-in-half tiles back into the channel saying they are levelers!  His only advice for the open roof tiles was stuffing steel wool into the humps!  Go figure.  The endings of the humps at the edge of the roof are all blocked by tin , so why not the those open humps on the upper?